# How to create a fuzzy search for names separated by spaces in lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

I want to build a lucene index where each document value will have 4-5 words.

I then want to have some kind of fuzzy search for it. But at first, I'm just trying to match a simple 2-word mest phrase. But it does not work. What is wrong in the following example?

```
Directory index = new RAMDirectory();
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_4_9);
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_4_9, analyzer);
IndexWriter w = new IndexWriter(index, config);
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new TextField("name", "TEST ASD", Field.Store.YES));
w.addDocument(doc);
w.close();

FuzzyQuery q = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("name", "test asd"));
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(DirectoryReader.open(index));
TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(1, true); //only get the top scored doc
searcher.search(q, collector);
ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
assertTrue(hits.length > 0); //FAILS
```

Comment: AFAIK `StandardAnalyzer` would result in two terms: `test` and `asd`, thus if you search for the term `test asd` it wouldn't match. You could try and use a `KeywordAnalyzer` which according to the doc should result in a single term but would not apply a lowercase filter, so either apply that yourself or build a custom analyzer using `KeywordTokenizer` and `LowerCaseFilter`.

Comment: So should I use a different analyer, or should I split my input strings by whitespace? What is the common approach in these cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have match on exach two terms - you could use TextField, but with KeywordAnalyzer (http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/KeywordAnalyzer.html) (it's also will save exact data and won't tokenize it)